# How do I add comments to my config file using QSettings?

Tags: c++, qt, config, qsettings

I'm writing a c++ code using qt and need an editable config file for my user to change some settings. In order to provide him some additional information I would like to add comments to my config file, however I cant find a way to mark them as comments.

I am using QSettings, my file is a .flt file. The usual '#' unfortunately does not seem to work with QSettings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using setting files in Qt and the QSettings class, you don't use the "usual"

> **#**

for defining a comment, but the

> **;**

instead...

so:

```
[abc]
key=val
;this is a comment in the QSettings
flag=true
```

Answer (score 0):

QSetting's INI file format uses MS Windows file format, which is

a) hierarchical and uses brackets [] for section names

b) uses ; to designate comment lines.

Note, thr default engine of QSetting would wipe any comments, because the whole mechanism is just serialization of name-value pairs from file and to file. To avoid that, a custom reader-writer class should be devised which would read and preserve comments somehow. QSettings supports custom formats by offering interface for read and write functions.